# Spacing sprite onscreen

Tags: ios, sprite-kit

Hi all I'm hoping someone can tell me how to decrease the spacing between sprites added from an array at the moment they are evenly spaced and centered but I need to decrease the width between the sprites

the whole block of code just incase is kind enough to test the spacing

```
int images = 5
     for(int i = 0; i < images; ++i)
         {
             ///load same ammount of spriteimages as images
            SKSpriteNode *sprite = 
            [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Null.jpg"];

            sprite.name = @"sprite.name =Sprite%d",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i];
            NSLog(@"***sprite.name %@",[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%i",i]);

             ///spriteSpacing
             float offsetFraction = ((float)(i + 1)) / (images + 1);
             float widthOfScreen =self.frame.size.width;

             sprite.position = CGPointMake(widthOfScreen * offsetFraction,self.frame.size.height/2 +200);
            [self addChild:sprite];
        }
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this and see what happens

```
float widthOfScreen = self.frame.size.width + 100.0;
```

Comment: Thanks hamobi, no this wont work.

widthOfScreen is basically the view (entire screen) so this would just add another 100 to the size of the view - and make the sprites more off center.

Answer (score 0):

in the end I did this

```
float padding = 100.0f;
        int blockWidth = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Null.jpg"].size.width;
        float xOffset = (self.frame.size.width - (blockWidth * images + padding * (images-1))) / 2;
        //float xOffset = (self.frame.size.width - (blockWidth * numberOfBlocks + padding * (numberOfBlocks-1))) / 2;
        float StartPoint = xOffset+blockWidth/2;
         for(int i = 0; i < images; ++i)
         {

        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Null.jpg"];


         ///set start point of 1st sprite to load 
         if (i>0&&i<images)
         {

             StartPoint = StartPoint+ blockWidth+padding;
         }

         //increment sprite position
         else if (i==images)
         {

              StartPoint = StartPoint+ blockWidth;
         }
         sprite.position = CGPointMake(StartPoint, self.frame.size.height * 0.8f);
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }
```

Comment: ... why not just set `float StartPoint = xOffset+blockWidth/2;` to `float StartPoint = xOffset+blockWidth/2 - padding;`  Then you can eliminate your if condition and just use `StartPoint = StartPoint+ blockWidth+padding;`

Comment: hmmm, didn't seem to work since as it adds the first sprite it also adds padding shifting all the sprite over (so no longer centering them) - have included code - just in case I did something wrong (am pretty new at this stuff)

float StartPoint = xOffset+blockWidth/2 - padding;
     for(int i = 0; i < images; ++i)
     {
        SKSpriteNode *sprite = [SKSpriteNode spriteNodeWithImageNamed:@"Null.jpg"];

         StartPoint = StartPoint+ blockWidth+padding;
         sprite.position = CGPointMake(StartPoint, self.frame.size.height * 0.8f);
        [self addChild:sprite];
    }

Comment: Then this answer does not work because the math is the same,  Lets say `origin = 0`, `BlockWidth = 2`, 'padding = 1`.   Your code, `SP = 0 + 2/2`. `SP is 1`,  hits If `SP = SP + 2`, so `SP is 3`.  My code `SP = 0 +2/2 - 1`. `SP is 0`, hits `SP = SP + 2 + 1`, so `SP is 3`

Comment: oh wait, never mind,  I thought you shifted if( i == 0), not i = images

Comment: I am now again confused as to what you are trying to do here,  why does the last block have a smaller gap?